# How can I make a statement wait until a previous function is finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I've got an issue where `window.open` gets called too quickly and my other function doesn't finish and post in time in my onclick function.

I tried setting a timeout on the `trackData()` but it only worked on occasion and I didn't want to set a longer timeout.

**onClick**

```
   {() => {
       trackData();
       window.open("https:google.com", "_self");
    })
```

any ideas?

EDIT: The following works locally but doesn't track when in production. Tracking works EVERYTIME if `"_self"` is being replaced with `"_blank"` (which it cannot be)

```
  let postData = async(value) => {
       await tracker({
            action: value,
        })
    }
```

tracker just makes an axios post with the action

```
   <div
       className="exampleBTN"
       onClick={() =>  {
       postData("example").then(                         
       window.open("https://google.com", 
       "_self")
       )}
    }
    >
   </div>
```

Locally, I can see the data going into the database.

However, online it doesn't work. It only works if either of these are true:

- Doesn't have window.open in the onClick
- doesn't have "_self" but "_blank" so it opens in a new tab

I thought my async was wrong so I also tried the following:

```
 onClick={async () =>  {
 await postData("example").then(                            
 window.open("google.com", "_self"))
 }}
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code? We don't know what trackData does, so there's little we can do.

Comment: @pytness, it's just an axios post. It's irrelevant to the question (I believe it is anyway).  trackData doesn't always finish posting before it opens a new window. If I take the "window.open" off the onClick - it makes the axios post everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with .then or async/await to do exactly this when action results in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Axios requests return Promises.

```
initiateAsynchronousAction()
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Callback inside the `.then` function will only be executed if the promise is fulfilled by the action executed by the async function.

Minor clarification:
Note that inside the `.then()` you have to pass a callback function and not just immediately invoke actions you want to perform, even if you don't plan to use the result value. So it will be
`.then(result=> console.log('Inside callback!'))`

and **not**
`.then(console.log('Inside callback!'))`

Async-await is another way to write this, it is simply syntactic sugar, that is just an easier way to write it:

```
const foo = async () => {
  const result = await initiateAsynchronousAction()
  console.log(result)
}
```

The variable `result` will only be given the value once the Promise is resolved. That is, the assigning of the value will be awaited.

You can chain a `.catch` in the first case or envelop the task in a try-catch block to catch errors if the Axios promise is unfulfilled.

Comment: @UnluckyLAD you could add more code here. It is unclear as to what the tracker function does. Does it return a Promise? Also, inside the `.then()` you have to pass a callback function and not just immediately invoke `window.open()` even if you don't plan to use the result value. So it will be `.then((result)=> window.open())`

Answer (score 1):

you can use promise based approache here.use `aysnc` and `await` for that.

```
async function trackData(){
 ..... 
   let data = awiat your code 
.....
}
```

function call with promise

```
trackData().then(res=>{
  if(res ==="Success){
 window.open("https:google.com", "_self")
}
})
```